# Where in my cross-posted question should I mention that the question is cross-posted?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, cross-posting, rules

What I understand about cross-posting: Usually, don't. But whenever you do (like if it's really justified to do so), then mention it.

Ok, assuming for the sake of argument that something is allowed to be and is cross-posted: **Where in the post do I mention that it is cross-posted?**

1. At the top of the post (before people have a chance to choose to read something that is cross-posted)?
2. At the bottom of the post (after people may have already read the post, and have probably even made some notes in an effort to answer the question)?
3. Other?

---

**Context**: I was told Choice 2 here: [Is there anything to improve in this post which is about ambiguity in question about field axioms?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34125/is-there-anything-to-improve-in-this-post-about-ambiguity-in-question-about-fie/34126#34126)

**An idea**: Reddit does sometimes both top and bottom and sometimes just bottom. Not so familiar with reddit but if you use the 'crosspost' button then you can see both top and bottom. But I've seen people post the same thing without using the crosspost button and it ends up just bottom. (Not sure if reddit allows that but they do find out about the crosspost without the button because you see it at the bottom ultimately.)

**Idk but from what I know**: the reason why I was told to not cross-post (at least without mentioning it) is that people may waste time on 1 site when it's asked somewhere else. I mean even if the post isn't (or isn't anywhere near) an exact replica. If there are similarities, then it could still waste time if it's just at the end.

But whatever if it's better to put at the bottom, then ok. But I don't want to waste time of anyone who's/who would be/who would have been generously helping me, and I also don't want to be criticsed/judged by people in the future like: *"Hey why did you mention the cross-post only at the bottom? Why are you wasting time of people who are generously helping you?"* In this case, I want to be able to link to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370160/where-in-my-cross-posted-question-should-i-mention-that-the-question-is-cross-po) and be justified in putting cross-post notices at the bottom to defend myself from criticism/judgement.

Comment: Since I am the user who gave you that suggestion in the linked post, let me clarify my position. You asked for feedback on improving your question posted on Mathematics SE. My impression was that your post needed a *lot* of focus. So, in your case, (re)moving any commentary that is not directly aimed at clarifying your question would have been a good thing. I am not aware of any network-wide (or even [site-specific](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting) policies on this, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: FWIW, I have also seen the cross-posting note put only in the comments, and that also works fine, in my opinion. But in your case, the comment thread was already extended quite a lot, and such a comment may have been buried in there and been missed, which is why I did not suggest that in my answer that you linked.

Comment: Arguably this question should contain the answer to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87739/282094 and if not there, then the FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu - but neither does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend never cross-posting a question by simply copy/pasting it from one site to another.  If that is what you want to do, then I think you should delete it from the original site, and re-ask it as a new question on the new site.

If you are not copy/pasting, and instead are writing a new question on a new site that in some way relates to a question that you are leaving on its original site, then I would not consider that to be a cross-post. The way I recommend to reference it is by writing somewhere in your new and old question bodies something like:

> This question relates to a question that I posted on SITE_X as
> `https:SITE_Y/stackexchange.com/questions/YOUR_QUESTION_NUMBER` but it
> is not the same question because here I am asking ... whereas there I am asking
> ...

I think it will usually be best to provide this context to your question at or near the beginning of its body but there may be occasions when, for readability, it is better to mention it further down.

Comment: i knew it. so you disagree with The Amplitwist's answer in maths se meta? thanks! Edit: you could've mentioned that you edited your answer you know...

Comment: @BCLC I agree with much but not all of that multiparty answer.

Comment: ah wrong question i mean the part about the crosspost notice at the bottom instead of the top?

Comment: PolyGeo, ah wrong question i mean the part about the crosspost notice at the bottom instead of the top?

Comment: @BCLC I think I've already addressed that in my answer.  A "crosspost notice" should never be used to point between graduated sites because such cross-posts should not exist.  On the other had if a question on one site relates to another question on another site I would normally mention that near its top.

Comment: PolyGeo not in general i mean in this particular case of The Amplitwist's [answer in maths se meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34125/is-there-anything-to-improve-in-this-post-which-is-about-ambiguity-in-question-a/34126#34126)

Comment: @BCLC I don't know how the Maths community prefers to handle a "crosspost notice" so I only plan to answer in the general case.  Personally, I prefer not to use footnotes in my SE posts.

Answer (score 5):

Cross-posting, in the strict sense of copy-pasting, is [generally discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

However, if your question is based on a fundamental aspect and you want to post **two substantially different variations** that make them related but distinct, and are on-topic on different sites and the linked question adds relevance to the overall context, then **I would choose choice 1**:

> at the top of the post (before people have a chance to choose to read something that is cross posted)

However, **in case the linked question and its answers do not substantially add to the context**, then it can be taken as a sort of footnote, as described in choice 2

> at the bottom of the post (after people may have already read the post and have probably even made some notes in an effort to answer the question)

Comment: choice 1 got it thanks bad_coder