# Detect cross-site duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, cross-posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we automate detection of cross-posting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105847/can-we-automate-detection-of-cross-posting)

I've been seeing this fairly often lately; a user posts the same *exact* post, word for word, on multiple sites at once. Now I know that sometimes questions can be relevant to multiple sites, but when someone is entering the exact same body text on multiple sites, they're pretty clearly just throwing crap at the wall to see what sticks.

Would it be reasonable (and feasible) to block the posting of a post that *exactly* matches the body text of another question recently asked by that same user on another Stack Exchange site? IMO there's two relevant bits of info a warning should bring to the user's attention:

1. If you're trying to reask this question on a more relevant site, please flag `[your original question on site](link to question on other site)` for migration to the site you feel it's more appropriate.
2. If you're attempting to target a similar question to a different audience, consider rewording your original question to meet the new audience. Phrasing a question for (original site) can be very different from a question on (current site).

Just brainstorming, but I think this would be really nice to have. The filter should let you edit your post and post it (IMO) but I really, really don't see a valid use case for posting the exact same question, word for word, on multiple sites within a short period of time; at that point it's clearly a misuse of the system. Giving the user some guidance on what to do would save moderators, users and the original poster some headaches as everyone closes/deletes/plays hot potato with the cross-posted questions.

Comment: @YannisRizos arg, didn't see that, I'll add my idea as an answer there