# Best procedure in case of questionable scope?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

In case I'm not sure which stack community is the best place to ask a given question how should I proceed? Ask in both places and learn from the reaction?

Comment: Crossposting is not agreeable as I know.

Answer (score 3):

Only post your question once where you think it's best by reading the FAQ on both sites.

If it is in the wrong place, close votes or a moderator can move it the correct community.