# CruiseControl/server configuration - appropriate for Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser

I've recently asked a question about [CruiseControl.NET configuration which has to do with Windows Server 2008 administrator credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603566/how-to-run-a-cruisecontrol-task-as-administrator-in-windows-server-2008).

Is this an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, or Super User? Is there a (kind) way to ask the question on both sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [CruiseControl.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cruisecontrol.net/info) is a continuous integration/build server, it falls under the programming tools category, meaning it is a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

We do not like cross posting, so posting on both sites is not allowed (and may get you in trouble). We don't currently have a way to have a post show on two or more sites, though [this has been requested here before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

As a note - if you are not sure, you should ask *here* before posting on a potentially bad site for the question.

Comment: cross posting on where? ;)