# cross-posting questions between SO and infant beta SE site

Tags: discussion, beta-sites, cross-posting

The [Magento.SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) community is small (1300+ users, but hopefully growing). If I have a question about Magento code, I might rather post it on SO in hopes of getting more and better help than Magento.SE. However, I might wish to repost it on Magento.SE to get the most help I can get and *to help build the community*.

Related questions have been asked before, and I know the policy is to not do it and to figure which is more applicable. But what if the case is this .. where the Magento community is in infant stage. Sorry if that makes no difference.

Comment: There indeed is no difference. Pick a site and stick to it.

Comment: If you ask it, they will come.

Comment: You should post on Magento.se if your want it's traffic and community  participation to increase...

Comment: @Xarcell It's a tradeoff between that and actually getting my question answered that is my concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You should try to avoid this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

My recommendation is: ask on Magento first. *If* you don't get a useful answer there after a reasonable amount of time (a couple of days at minimum), then post a question on Stack Overflow *informed by your experience on Magento* - that is to say, don't just duplicate the text, but rather explain why the answer(s)<sup>*</sup> you got there didn't work, include more background information, what you've found in the meantime, etc.

...Then, if you *do* get a good answer on SO, go back and write up your conclusions as an answer to your own question on Magento.

<sup>*If your question didn't get any attention at all, just delete it.</sup>

Comment: RE: your footnote about deleting if it did not get any answers, would it be better to just flag for migration?  Even the migration link on SO might attract some attention to the infant SE site from someone unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Sounds like a pain in the rear to me, and isn't accurate for questions that arent off-topic.