# Is it OK to post the same question on several Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, cross-posting

Area 51 allows the creation of sites by several users.

This finally created a special behavior where several Stack Exchange sites have similar purposes to those of the [original trilogy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/).

This has to do with the fact that some questions are suitable for several sites.

So if a question has low views on a site, is it OK to post the same question on a site with a larger audience?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: I would say the accepted answer there also answers this.

Comment: @Oded : This is because I was thinking to ask this [question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/47657/36301) on ServerFault and modifying it for asking softwares instead of theory.

Comment: Looks like it is most suitable where it is. It has only been **two hours** and this is the holiday season to boot. Patience is a virtue.

Comment: @Oded : Well this is the problem with stackexchange, If a question get no-vote and low view in 1 hour, then don't expect to it to get 10 more views in the year.

Comment: You will find a much lower "hit rate" on forums. Consider that sometimes a question gets no-votes and low views because it is low quality and/or does not have enough detail. Not saying yours is, but consider that this can be a reason.

Comment: In general, the problem you are describing is due to human nature. Not something we can fix at Stack Exchange, I fear.

Comment: @user2284570 there are ways to bump questions. Valid edits, bounty... if it's a good question even asking nicely in chat to have a look.

Comment: @Oded : I've learned [this](http://serverfault.com/q/484707/203649) : Duplicate question beetween stackexchange site: a question is suitable for two site, you ask it on one site, but someone already asked it on another stackexchange site. Maybe the duplicate flagging menu would need to be updated for working on the whole stackexchange domains?

Comment: @ShadowWizard : any thoughts about this?

Comment: @user2284570 about what exactly? Your original question here or one of the comments?

Comment: @ShadowWizard : I've learned this : Duplicate question beetween stackexchange site: a question is suitable for two site, you ask it on one site, but someone already asked it on another stackexchange site. Maybe the duplicate flagging menu would need to be updated for working on the whole stackexchange domains?

Comment: @user2284570 no, it won't make much sense to mark question as duplicate of question asked in a different site. If you posted a question on site A  then discovered it's already asked in site B, you can flag your own post, ask to migrate it to site B and there it can be closed as duplicate. All is good. :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You only have one question to ask yourself :

> Is the question I'm about to ask, On-Topic ?

And to make exactly sure it is, on each website, you have the *What topics can I ask about here*.

If it fits there, well it doesn't matter if you asked it on 20 different sites as each sites will be consulted by their very specific community. So once again, make sure it's on topic and ask the question.

Comment: I'd love to know what's wrong with that.

Comment: Cross posting interferes with migrations, in particular when a question happens to be off-topic on one of the sites it was cross posted to. It is better to choose **one** site, where it is most suitable and let moderators migrate if needed.