# Etiquette, rules, or advice on which site to pose a question? (Or, why are there so many StackExchange sites?)

Tags: support, reputation, etiquette, old-questions, site-crossover

Basically:
I have a question I want to ask regarding using Apple's AppleScript/Objective-C bridge (Objective C wrapped in AppleScript, basically) to implement an HTML/WebKit-based pager (a drop-in for `less`, like `vimpager`) and a HTML-ized manpage writer, which should also be capable of rendering to PDF via pandoc/pdftex, etc.

Is this a:

- Stack Overflow question? (C/Objective-C, APIs)
- Ask Different question? (AppleScript)
- Unix & Linux question? (implementing a pager which is a drop-in for a *nix utility)
- TeX question? (PDF rendering)
- All of the above?

Where and how should I ask this, in order to increase the likelihood of the "right person" seeing it?

---

**Edit:** I believe this question was too hastily closed as a duplicate.

While the best **answer** to this question is indeed identical to **answer** to the other:

> Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. If ... it does not get any answer,   **ask a moderator to migrate the question, or alternatively, delete it and re-ask it.**

The so-called "duplicate" in question asks

> Is cross-posting permitted on multiple Stack Exchange sites if the question is on topic?

whereas this question asks,

> Where and how should I ask this [ question that is on topic on multiple Stack Exchange sites? ]

---

That is to say, *if two similar but materially different questions have identical **answers**,

it does not necessarily follow that the **questions** are likewise the same.*

Calling them duplicate questions does a disservice to both and the site in general I think.

Comment: Just saw: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/249673. But I'd still like maybe a little advice here, if that's ok.

Comment: +1 "If two similar but materially different questions have identical answers, it does not necessarily follow that the questions are likewise the same." I've been bitten by this a few times myself on AskDifferent.

Answer (score 3):

Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to involve a programming problem in some way, usually involving code.  If it's a programming problem involving code, and you can ask the question in a way that's definitively answerable by a software engineer, it will generally be considered on-topic there.

Note that the "site scope" for every Stack Exchange Site can be found in the Help Center, under "What questions can I ask here?"  These articles are very specific about the kinds of questions that are acceptable on each site.  Stack Overflow's site scope page is here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: True. But it doesn't follow that site scopes are in any way mutually exclusive.

One can have coding questions fully within the scope of another site, c.f. how to use [lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_(programming)) via [blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)) and a [bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC) rather than [load self-modifying code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1070) in a language without lexical scope. And exclusive to Apple. 100% Stack Overflow, 100% Ask Different.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the verbiage you use in your question for it to be considered on-topic. I think that your question is a good fit for SO or the Ask Different site if you ask it using the following guidelines:

1. Describe the problem clearly. It should be a problem that is solveable without adding too much opinion in the answer and isn't so broad that would require paragraphs to describe the solution.  **Word your question in such a way that the answer provided will be as simple and rudimentary as possible**
2. Showcase what you have tried thus far to solve the problem (ie. show your source code thus far, if this isn't a coding related question, you're in the wrong place!)
3. Describe the errors you are getting along with the error information (stack trace, etc.)
4. Provide any supporting evidence to show why you think you doing something right, in the event someone sees where you went wrong and provides clarification to your thought process.

What will *not* help you is if you...

1. Simply ask for code and show no attempt being made to resolve your issue.
2. Not providing a clear, succinct description
3. Not providing a sample of the code you have tried.

Also, please keep in mind that if you have an existing question, closed or not, always try to edit that question to improve it, and cast a vote to get it reopened if it was closed. Keep in mind that if you have too many questions that are closed, you run the risk of being question banned.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! It just occurred to me:

Though **duplicate** cross-site questions aren't allowed, is it acceptable to rephrase then re-ask _basically_ the same question on a different site, if the first you tried failed to garner a sufficient, noting that you had, indeed, tried the other first?

Comment: Also, +1 (if I could) for "try editing...". I had wondered about that; but hadn't ever done so because that use case doesn't seem to be addressed in:
```
How to Edit
  - fix grammatical or spelling errors
  - clarify meaning without changing it
  - correct minor mistakes
  - add related resources or links
```

Comment: If your question is rephrased, understandable, _and_ on-topic for the site in question, I feel that it would be okay.  In some cases, it may be beneficial to share that you did try asking on another SE site and didn't get a response so you're posting again with a more detailed post.  Just be sure your new post really is differentiated from your old post to remove any possibility of it being closed.  Just my two cents on this.  Cheers.

Comment: @GeoffNixon: If your question was posted to the wrong site in the first place, it's also highly likely to have quality problems.  You would need to fix those first before considering moving your question

Comment: @RobertHarvey, agreed. I should have stated that the question should always be improved, regardless of the fact if it's closed or not. Will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @GeoffNixon:  I had a nearly-identical question and have been somewhat frustrated because of the perceived overlap between exchanges... I'm still interested in a definitive answer to your (and my) question.