# Why does SE not force users to ask in the relevant community?

Tags: discussion, questions

Why does SE not force, or at least 'push', users to post their questions in the relevant communities?

E.g. WordPress.

SO allow users to post WP questions in Stack Overflow and do not make much of an effort (if any) to get them to post it on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

It would be easy to detect when the user types 'wordpress' into the title, or when he selects 'wordpress' as a tag for the question, and create a popup message accordingly - asking (or even forcing) the user to go to wordpress.stackexchange.com.

As I believe it would be quite easy to enforce, my question isn't why don't they try, it's more 'why don't they care'?

If they weren't bothered about giving each community it's deserved amount of traffic, why would they bother making different subdomains for these different communities?

Comment: Why **should** these be "enforced"? What if a question is on-topic on two (or three, or four) sites? Which one is the right one? What's the benefit to the user (and community) of such enforcement?

Comment: I suppose. But it's got me going round in circles...  What's the point of having a separate WordPress community then? 99% of questions can be correctly put into multiple tags. It's splitting people up and making it less likely that your question will be answered.

Comment: @Dan.: [The value of separate sites has been discussed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240572/do-we-really-need-all-these-computer-science-programming-places).

Comment: Blimey! I thought the Meta sites were places for discussion where you couldn't possibly ask a stupid question! Won't happen again

Answer (score 7):

We don't force them, because it's not that easy to get it right.

How would you tell that a question belongs on WordPress.SE? We have the "wordpress" tag on Stack Overflow precisely because there are WordPress questions that are perfectly on-topic there, that don't need to be migrated to WordPress.SE - and might not even be welcome there.
So the fact that that tag is used, or that the product is mentioned in the title, does not imply that it should be on another site.

If I have a problem with the programming side of WordPress, and am typing it into Stack Overflow - the *last* thing I want is a popup asking me "Don't you want to post this on WordPress.SE?" That is just an annoying distraction.

There is also a bit of overlap between sites; some questions might be applicable on both Stack Overflow and WordPress. As another example, some questions are appropriate for both Information Security and Super User. This overlap would further complicate the matter.