# What can I do when I'm up-against high rep users that are using the system to their own liking instead of as it should be used?

Tags: discussion

This thing isn't about my specific closed question here. It's really about the issue of a small group of the most active users in a site affecting the masses in negative ways.

---

I feel like I'm being "crowd bullied" on Programmers SE. I've disagreed with a few users there in the past. Those people are the most active on the site, and seem to set trends in how questions are received.

I'd like to discuss this question which *I did cross post* (but only in a form that was 100% on topic and valuable in both communities) on Programmers SE and Info Security SE in order to get specialized answers from each group (not just to throw my question in two places and get a quick answer). Note that I did announce that the question was cross posted.

*Let me be clear that no one claimed that this question was off-topic. There's no dispute about off-topic involved here.*

> I'm [cross posting this question from Programmers.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72091/is-it-fundamentally-possible-to-validate-that-an-unmodified-version-of-your-clie) because I
>   think it's equally on-topic here and would like to pose the question
>   to this community as well.
>
> This seems like a programming question but it's really a fundamental
>   security question too.
>
> ---
>
> **Is it fundamentally possible to validate that an unmodified version of your client connects to your server?**
>
> I was just thinking about the idea of having my client-side app hash
>   it's own source code and send that as a key to the server with any
>   requests as proof that it's unmodified, but that's silly because
>   anyone could just have the client send a hash of the unmodified
>   version via a modified version.
>
> I was wondering if there might be a secure way to do this though, via
>   some sort of proof that the client was unmodified.

On Info Security SE, the question [was heavily up-voted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72091/is-it-fundamentally-possible-to-validate-that-an-unmodified-version-of-your-clie) and recieved multiple great answers.

On Programmers SE, [it was down voted, put on hold, and not re-opened](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261478/is-it-fundamentally-possible-to-validate-that-an-unmodified-version-of-your-clie/261481#261481) after I complied with all edit suggestions. The [Meta discussion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6973/was-this-really-a-broad-question/6976?noredirect=1#comment19927_6976) I posted about it, and the user who posted an answer in that discussion in heavy support of my question, were heavily down-voted.

It was first said to be **"too broad"**, and I was asked to remove a large portion of my question, which I complied with.

It was then, after I worked to improve the question as asked, said to be **"too specific / yes or no".**

It's not a matter of being on-topic at this point, now it's a personal matter of being the kind of questions that those active in the two communities like to see.

So I feel like I'm playing a game of whack-a-mole. I want to be able to utilize Programmers.SE, but many times in the past this kind of thing has happened. I think at this point it isn't even worth trying to use that site.

**What can I do when I'm up-against high rep users that are using the system to their own liking instead of as it should be used?**

---

I recognize that my final comments and edits are not well handled and un-professional; at that point I was fed up, felt bullied, and fought back a bit.

I feel like this is misuse of the system. SE isn't a place for people to take over like the big kids on the playground, choosing question style on preference, and banding together to block any questions they don't like. A good on-topic question shouldn't be closed.

Comment: "100% on topic and valuable in both communities" - you might say this and even truly believe this, but with all due respect, if long time members of a community decide otherwise it's likely they are correct and you are wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree. But it was never disputed that it was off-topic. That claim was not made at all. Everyone seems to agree as far as it being on-topic.

Comment: Different sites have different *communities*. Yes, that means that essentially the same post may be received differently by those communities. That's kind of by design.

Comment: However, Meta SE is the wrong place to discuss this. This is really a topic for Programmers.SE, since this is an issue you have with the community *there*.

Comment: Isn't it a rule that you're not supposed to cross-post on multiple SE sites?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I *did* discuss it there, and look how *that* turned out.

Comment: @Louis yes, *except* when it's specifically on topic and valuable in each site in the form posted. What's frowned upon is people throwing their questions in a bunch of places where it's not even a good fit for the sites.

Comment: I can't post anything there without being down-voted by that ultra-active niche that seem to band together. I think my question should be re-opened.

Comment: @jt0dd: So what do you want us to do about it? Meta SE is not Programmers. We don't get to tell how that community runs the site.

Comment: As you said you got some great answers on Info Security. That by definiton made it perfect on-topic and suited for that community and foremost you got some perfect answers to your question. Why bother that it didn't fly on programmers? Only for *justice*? Why not just accept that you and the programmers.se community don't go well together?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want you to say, from an un-biased perpspective, "Based on the official guidelines set by Programmers SE, the question *should* be re-opened." I'm just looking for an un-biased *opinion/discussion* on the problem. I just want someone to see it with un-biased eyes.

Comment: @rene idk man.. I don't like bullies. I guess that's why.

Comment: @jt0dd: You won't find those eyes *here*. That is and will remain the prerogative of each site's community.

Comment: @jt0dd: try and keep an open mind and try to assume good faith. By calling a community 'bullies' you are not going to win support. Just because you don't like their standards doesn't mean that they are wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well I won't find them *there*. Stack Exchange is a public tool for the world (including me) to use. It's not a place for people to group up and refuse question that they don't *like*. It has to go according to the *system*.

Comment: @jt0dd: I have not seen that attitude there myself. Make sure you didn't bring antagonism *with you*, at all times, or you'll find it everywhere before long.

Comment: @jt0dd: You have it wrong, I'm afraid. There are no 'general guidelines' (other than mostly no shopping questions, no open-ended discussions, and other general *off*-topic guidelines) for what is on topic on a site. You don't get to tell a community what to accept.

Comment: @MartijnPieters alright, but just because it hasn't happened to you doesn't mean it won't. I wouldn't be the first to talk of high rep users on a site trying to run things the wrong way :/

Comment: @MartijnPieters - While I concur, a few, active, high-rep users also shouldn't get to tell the rest of the less active community what to accept.

Comment: @jt0dd: Start by ditching your absolute ideas about right and wrong. There are no absolutes when it comes to human interaction. Who are you to tell them that they are doing it wrong? That already sets you on the wrong footing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That goes both ways.

Comment: @codenheim: this has nothing to do with high-reputation, but everything with investments made. There is a correlation, but the users got the high reputation *because* they invested in the site. And that counts for *everything*. So yes, they do get a lot to say, not because they have reputation but because they are *active*.

Comment: I suggest you invite the high-rep members of programmers.se in a chatroom for an hour, maybe moderated by a CM, and all of you should do two things, listen to each other and listen to each other. Listening is best done with your mouth closed.

Comment: @codenheim: the thing then, is to *invest yourself too*. Become an active member of the community, so that people get to know you and your voice counts for something. Don't just *barge in* and demand that your way is the right way and the other way wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well if a few people can participate often in this great system that exists within SE and be granted the right to suppress the participation of others as they see fit... something's wrong there.

Comment: I'm personally invested. What has that got to do with people ignoring the "Be Nice" rule?

Comment: @Shog9 - be aware of this issue. I love SE and I hope a few highly active individuals aren't allowed to oppress the masses. They have the power to do so now. That little "close" vote and recognized name go a long way when those users act on thousands of questions per week. I realize that SE needs those users, but perhaps they should be moderated by some higher authority in a few cases.

Comment: @jt0dd - I tried to advocate for you yesterday. The only advice I can give you now is to ask questions impeccably, as not to give anyone occasion to close your question; and to avoid engaging people who aren't in your best interest. You've seen already the outcome of that.

Comment: @codenheim yes, I agree. I got the answer to my question! I just thought it might we worth it to discuss the issue of high rep users controlling the masses by sheer activity levels. This is such a great system, and my case here is insignificant campared to the issue as a whole. It's just a simple example, and I wanted to see what others had to say about it. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I went from #1 in the daily ranking (just pointing out I am "invested") to now leaving the P.SE community over this. I don't have time to waste with intolerance and minority activist establishmentarianism. (Not trying to use big words, but that is the best way I can describe it). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False-consensus_effect (it also goes goes both ways). I wish you luck. There _are_ a lot of good people there (and here).

Comment: @codenheim I fully agree. Have a good one!

Comment: So... since you disagree with your question being closed, *obviously* the high rep users are wrong and being bullies?

Comment: @hichris123 no. You missed the whole point. Sorry.

Comment: @jt0dd The most authoritative source I found re cross-posting is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/241526). The answer with the most upvotes answers "**NO**" to whether crossposting is allowed. The 2nd most upvoted is also against it. The one answer that mentions exceptions comes in third place and has a comment from Jeff Atwood that the posts should be "tailored to each audience on the different sites" and should be "materially different in each case". Your crosspost did not meet this requirement.

Comment: @Louis but could it have really been, outside of saying "As a programmer, I'm wondering.." and "As an info security enthusiast I'm wondering..."? That **can't** apply to certain questions, which simply fit in both places as they are.

Comment: @Louis and on your **"NO"** answer, there's a comment with 46 upvotes saying **"No offense, but this answer is nonsense."**

Comment: I have read the whole story on here and on P.SE (main and meta sites) and I am getting the same impression as @hichris123...

Comment: @jt0dd Selective quoting. Your replies are coming across as disingenuous.

Comment: @Gone well, maybe you're part of the problem.

Comment: @jt0dd so because I *dare* not to agree with you and *dare* to not follow your 'crusade' against people who *dare* to not follow your thinking, that makes me 'part of the problem'?

Comment: @Gone no, simply because you choose to ignore the problem having not experienced it.

Comment: @jt0dd how very little you know about me and my experiences here.  I am not ignoring the problem, I do not see that there is a problem - quite a big difference

Comment: @Louis looking at Jeff Atwoods comment, I would say you're right about my cross-post being wrong. However, that isn't the issue here.

Comment: @Gone I know one thing: You forgot to read the "Be Nice" rule!

Comment: @jt0dd disagreeing with you does not mean being not nice.  I am not the one name calling.

Comment: @Gone Good point. I let frustration get to me in that situation.

Comment: @jt0dd that happens to all of us - human nature; however, it is up to us as individuals to control that urge (sometimes easier said than done).

Comment: I [gave up on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/1130/rachel) a long time ago. Most other users that think the same way left too, and the majority of active users left are ones that have a very strict definition of the type of question they want. And in my opinion, the site name no longer matches the type of question they want to support, which leads to a lot of closed questions, and a frustrated and harsher community.

Answer (score 26):

The high-rep users aren't "using the system to their own liking." Don't go into a site acting like you know everything. The Duke Nuke'm ego attitude doesn't go over well on this network. They're enforcing quality restrictions that have been in place a long time and help keep their site clean and up to standards. If you don't understand that, then you have two options:

1. **Work harder to understand the scope of the site and develop a better understanding of that community.** The fact that it was accepted on another site has *absolutely no bearing* on it's topicness on another. It's completely irrelevant, and should not even be mentioned, anymore. Useless information - seriously. Your question on Meta Programmers gave you plenty of valuable information that perfectly well explained why your question was not acceptable for their site. Might I quote the most relevant part:

   > The post here shows no effort at all. It shows no level of comprehension of the nature of the problem. It asks a very broad question to a relatively well known problem.

   This explains wonders about the Programmers SE community, mainly their expectation of a basic comprehension of the problem, and some research that shows you've made an effort in figuring it out yourself. Again, these expectations are specific to that community, and whether or not those expectations are present on Security SE has no bearing on your question on Programmers SE.

   Yet, you seem to have completely ignored that part of the answer. Perhaps you were too distracted on the inaccurate representation of your question as a one-liner after you edited, but whatever. The unedited question is still lacking in those expectations, so it makes sense that both versions would be closed. Most interesting, though, is that you accepted an answer that doesn't even answer your question. It doesn't say anything about the topicness of your question at all. Let me summarize that for you:

   > No. He edited the question and you still closed it. Someone answered the question and still voted to close it. The question was acceptable on Security SE.

   Ok, well editing a question doesn't miraculously make it acceptable. Someone answering the question and still voting to close it really has nothing to do with anything. And as I said before, its topicness on another site is not relevant. So your accepted answer says absolutely nothing to support your argument that it's a good question, which only leads me to believe you don't really care about the feedback and only care about someone agreeing with you. And to be perfectly honest, everything you've written here in your question and comments seems to support that theory.
2. **Don't participate in that community.** I'm not saying you should just give up because you're never going to fit in, no. I'm saying that there is absolutely nothing wrong with ceasing participation in a community that didn't turn out to be what you expected. I've done the exact same thing with a Stack Exchange community myself. I had a presumed idea of what the community was, it didn't turn out to be what I thought, and I left. No harm done, no feelings hurt - just wasn't for me. If you try too hard to fit in, you only make yourself stand out more.

Comment: In your current version, the second sentence of the intro paragraph would likely fit better within point #1 than as part of the intro (the first and third sentences fit together - the second one being there is a bit jarring from one idea to another back to the first).