# What to do when moderators are too busy to look at your flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

On Stack Overflow, I raised a custom flag on one of my own questions a month ago.

> **Flagged Posts for TheIndependentAquarius**
>
> *2* [Error: QOpenGLShader: could not create shader - while running through ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760215/error-qopenglshader-could-not-create-shader-while-running-through-ssh) *1*
>   asked Feb 27 at 8:07 by TheIndependentAquarius
>
> This problem currently occurs on Ubuntu system. Please move this question
>   to ubuntu.SE since it hasn't got any attention here.
>   – TheIndependentAquarius Mar 9 at 10:48   *pending*

This question is important to me.

What to do when moderators are too busy to look at the flag?

Comment: If it's urgent for you and a valid request, you can try your luck in a chat room where moderators also take part, ask nicely and one of them might do it. Just don't push it too much and it should be OK.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am scared that people there will think of me as a leech! :(

Comment: That's why it's vital to ask nicely. Not barge in and write "Handle my flag", first explain why, etc

Comment: The flag has been handled now; the post was migrated to Unix.SE.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup, Oded is a good person. :)

Answer (score 11):

There are over 1700 flags in the Stack Overflow flag queue at this time.

And some of the moderators are not as active as they were; There is a moderator election running to address this.

The result is that flags take time to get to - in particular as some types of flags get handles faster than others (spam/offensive flags will be handled before any other type of flag, for instance), and "Other" flags tend to be the last handled ones, since each and every one of them is different and requires a high level of cognitive resources to handle (compared to the other types of flags), as a moderator needs to investigate the issues.

So, a month since flagging can be expected on Stack Overflow at this time.

---

What to do?

Participate in the election. Get people who will help with the flag queue elected.

Other than that? Wait patiently.

Comment: Can I simply copy this SO question and paste it on ubuntu site?

Comment: We don't particularly like [cross posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), especially when a question can be seen as belonging on the original site.

Comment: I know that but even after raising the bounty (and not getting answer) and flagging the question (and not getting response) - **can your stated rule not be relaxed for genuine reasons** or it is written on stone?

Comment: I contacted one of the askubuntu moderators, who said "We've had questions like that in the past - quickly ignored because its a specialty Question. Probably better on SO."

Comment: I will migrate to [unix.se] - which seems to be a better place for the question.

Comment: I should also point out that we try to triage flags, using some crude userscripts, and migration flags tend to fall to the bottom of that. Migrations usually aren't that urgent, and they require a judgment of both post quality and understanding of what exactly is on topic at the target site. They're a pain to handle, so we tend to put them off and focus on more urgent things, like people breaking the rules of the site.

Comment: Oded - Thanks for the helpful attitude.