# What can/should I do when my flags have 'unusually' been pending for too much time?

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags

In a site I'm active in, moderators approve when a user flags some old comments as "obsolete", "too chatty" etc. (All such flags I've raised have been marked helpful) It's a relatively small community, and thus flags don't piled up like they do in SO. I imagine flagging such ancient comments isn't as well-received on the trilogy since there are many more crucial and critical cases that need real mod attention.

Anyhow, I used to flag ~10 comments a day, and continued the next day, making sure my flags were helpful. Until Saturday, my flags got attention in the time span of a day, and I was a happy flagging teddy bear.

However, none of my mod attention flags have been processed since then. I have a bit of helpful flags after that, but obviously they've been removed through the VLQ queue. Had I not been a persistent flagger, I probably wouldn't have noticed this. I currently have 22 pending flags:

[image]

And it's been three days since the last mod flag has been processed. I'm not complaining or anything, I'm just asking

### Should I do something? What can I do?

I have already pinged one of the mods several times in chat, and he seems to be a bit busy. What if something happens **that will require instant mod attention**?

I already read [What to do when moderators are too busy to look at your flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253144/what-to-do-when-moderators-are-too-busy-to-look-at-your-flag); but I believe that's a bit different from my case: SO has a long queue of flags, and that's usual. The flags on *our* site have **unusually** been pending for too much time though. The rationale in the comments and the answer, thus, must be a bit different I suppose.

Comment: Same here. I got 100+ piled up flags on ELU since a week