# Are duplicate questions acceptable across sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I am still pretty new to Stack Exchange. I have posted a couple of questions that have not gotten very good answers. If I post an question on one site, and it does not a good solution, is it acceptable to post a duplicate question on another community?

Example:

I posted an issue I was having with the OS X terminal and finding the right port on Stack Overflow. I got a few answers, but nothing that good. The problem was with an Arduino port, so is it acceptable to post a duplicate answer on the [Arduino community](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) since they would know more about Arduinos and terminal issues?

Comment: gotta be a multidupe... Yep.  BTW, the [meta-tag:faq] tag has answers for many new user's questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, please don't do that.

For more information and the reasoning behind this see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)