# How to decide where a machine learning question belongs: the AI Stack Exchange site, Cross Validated, Data Science SE, etc

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If I have a machine learning question, I am able to post it in any of Cross Validated, Data Science SE, or AI SE. Does it make sense to have so many different places to post the same type of content rather than some consolidated place to post machine learning questions? Why should I pick one over another? All I'm able to infer from [Data science, Cross Validated and Artificial Intelligence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311537/data-science-cross-validated-and-artificial-intelligence) that CV is aimed for more theoretical problems and Data Science is for more applied questions.

- Where does that leave the AI SE?
- What incentive is there to ever post in the AI SE over one of the other two, given that the other two have larger communities and are more likely to get a response back?
- Also, since SE discourages cross-posting, how can I get my question to have the attention of both communities?

Comment: See also [this older question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266067/difference-between-the-cross-validated-and-data-science-se-sites?rq=1), AI.SE isn't about "implementation" and has far fewer visitors. [SO has over 6K AI questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) and by far the most visitors (**if** it's on-topic ask there). It's polite to wait a reasonable amount of time (even days) before trying another site, so be prepared to stick with where you ask. Also see the right column, with the "Related" links. If you can ask on AI.SE they need you.

Comment: As far as your last bullet, I'm afraid that there is no such built-in feature to get a question attention to multiple communities. There is a feature request asking for it at [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet), but that's been marked deferred. Posting a link to the question on one community in the other community's chat is an option/workaround.

Comment: As for your last point: have you tried their chatrooms?

Comment: I don't agree that Cross Validated is 'for more theoretical problems": a majority of questions arise from problems encountered in a wide variety of applications, & answers often provide eminently practical solutions (see e.g. [What should I do when my neural network doesn't learn?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/352036/17230).) Questions about writing code in a particular language or using a particular software package *are* off topic; so [How to get feature importance from RandomForest using scikit-multilearn library?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/67892/3361) would be ...

Comment: ... closed on CV. A good rule of thumb might be that if you'd be as happy to get an answer illustrated with R code as one with Python code (or vice versa), CV's the right site. You're also encouraged to make your questions understandable to those who don't write code in the same language or use the same software package as you.

Comment: I always has been, and continues to be, my strongly-held opinion that Data Science and AI should be merged into Cross Validated, and that the scope of Cross Validated should be expanded accordingly.