# Is cross-posting allowed on multiple sites if they use a different language?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, languages, cross-posting

I understand that simultaneously cross-posting on multiple SE sites is [considered inappropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917).

What about simultaneously cross-posting to two SE sites in a different language?  e.g., a user posts their question to both Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow en español?  In other words, the poster posts an English-language version of the question on Stack Overflow and at the same time posts a Spanish-language version of the question on Stack Overflow en español?  Is that allowed?

(No, I'm not trying to advocate for allowing it.  I just honestly want to know what the actual policy is.  For instance, I saw one user argue that it should be allowed [in a comment at Ru.SO](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559933/%25D0%259A%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B9-%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B5%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B4-%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BA%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D0%25BE-%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D1%2581%25D0%25BF%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B7%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F-%25D0%25B8%25D1%2581%25D0%25BF%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%25D1%258C%25D0%25B7%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D1%258C-%25D0%25B4%25D0%25BB%25D1%258F-%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B0%25D1%2581%25D1%2581%25D0%25B8%25D1%2584%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B8-%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D1%2584%25D1%2580-%25D1%2581%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B2&usg=ALkJrhjHCMTefjq_-DkvAbmcxPY83g32jw#comment728089_559933).  Is there a statement of our policy anywhere?  Is it site-dependent?)