# Is cross-posting an answer to similar questions on different Stacks acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers, cross-posting

To serve as a complimentary discussion to:

[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

At times the same question will asked on two different Stacks that have an overlapping scope by two different users, therefore the question itself is not considered a cross-post and will remain open on both sites...

As a user on both sites I see they are similar, very similar, in fact if the questions had been asked on the same Stack one of them would have been closed as a duplicate...

I have posted an answer to one of the questions already, a good answer, in fact an answer that would perfectly answer the question on the other Stack...

**Can I copy and paste this answer to new question on the other site?** (I will follow all current citing rules, giving credit to the original user.)

Comment: Yes, but you should credit to original user, as well as make it community wiki (you can't get rep for someone else's answer).

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Usually it is my own answer I want to copy, but fair point on credit. Although I have seen some other meta posts where you do not necessarily have to make the copied answer a community wiki....

Comment: @D.W. But when it is done by two different users? Why should stack or user be robbed of a valid question just because it was on a different stack? Are we supposed to tell user who ask a question that now have to search multiple stacks to find duplicates before they ask a question?

Comment: @Skooba, you are right, I missed that you were talking about two different users.  (That said, my experience is that if you get two questions asked by two different users on two different sites, it is rare that it is *exactly* the same question, and there may be opportunities to tailor  your answer to reflect the specifics of the question and the site.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It presumably is.

It probably is a *good* idea to cross reference an answer, and try to tailor your answer to the specific site - I would recommend something like

"This is very similar to my answer on U&L - LINK , so I'll be basing it off that"

It is very unlikely they will be identical, and at the very least it makes readers aware that you're not simply copy pasting everywhere blindly.

Other than that - it should presumably be a non issue.