# Where should multi-discipline questions go?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, cross-posting

Some questions can be answered in more than one dimensions. For example, a social phenomena can be explained by mathematical modelling, sociology theories, and / or political / economic theories. Should I post it on each site, stating from which dimension I expect the answer to come, or is it not a good fit for SE (violation of real questions have an answer)?

The question is different from [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). People who cross-post questions often seek the same answer from larger audiences. For example, if somebody cross posted "How can I achieve this in SQL Server?" on both SO and DBA, he or she is expecting more PROGRAMMERS to see the post.

However, I would like to post some question like "Why did Clinton lose the campaign?", and I'm expecting answers from statisticians on why the polls failed, answers from political scholars on the election system of the US, and maybe also psychologist, etc. I'm not cross posting to reach a larger audience of the same group (e.g. programmers), I want answers from DIFFERENT audiences.

Comment: If an answer has more than one possible answers, then its considered too broad, or primarily opinion based.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal: That's not really the case. A question that has more than one possible answer is totally fine and expected; only questions that have *lots* of different answers but *no objective criteria to distinguish relative quality* of the competing answers is Too Broad or POB.