# Is it legit to delete and repost a question that gets no answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, expired-bounty, reopened-questions

Is it legit to delete and repost a question that gets no answers, even if the bounty has expired and no one answered, although there were comments before the bounty? I have one such question. I am still trying to resolve it, but I don't know what else I should look for.

Comment: By "delete and reopen" do you actually mean delete and _repost?_ Otherwise your question doesn't make much sense

Comment: Yes. My question does is not answered yet and has not attracted much attention. I am also searching for a solution on my own. The bounty wasn't successful and I lost reputation.

Comment: @S4NNY1 - If you are not getting answers.  It means you need to improve and clarify the question.

Comment: Look at your old unanswered question. Did you do everything possible to make it "look" interesting? Is the title descriptive or way too broad? Have you shared your research? Do you have an idea where the problem lays? Is this a problem other users might have experienced in the past? Did you look in the archives? Did you check spelling, grammar and punctuation?

Comment: If you answered "yes" to all of these questions then there's not much else you can do. Deleting the old question and starting a new one from scratch is possible if it's a just a one-off thing, but if you haven't identified its weak points the end results will be the same.

Comment: But where / what should I look for. I am a newbie in an area. I read many forums, tried out different options. I also gave results for tries, that others on SO recommended. I lost my rep. and now what? Waiting till I have a better question?

Comment: See also [What should I do if no one answers my question?](/help/no-one-answers) in the help section.

Comment: Separately, there is obviously no guarantee that a bounty can bring up any answer, perhaps because your question is unanswerable. I can offer 167k bounty for anyone who is able to answer "How do I travel faster than the speed of light?" but because the only feasible answer (according to our current understanding of the universe) is "you can't", I probably won't receive any useful answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It *is* legitimate to delete and undelete a question, but it has no effect (it won't be bumped to the frontpage again).

Deleting and re*posting* the question is not allowed; that would amount to just [bump](/questions/tagged/bump)ing the question. If you do that too often, you'll attract attention of the ♦ moderators who might want to have a word with you.

Comment: What else can I do to receive an answer? I lost my bouty privilege due to low rep, so I cannot start a new bounty.

Comment: Answer more questions / ask more good questions so that you add value to the community, eventually getting back to a reputation level where you can add another bounty?

Comment: @S4NNY1 See [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/21960)

Comment: What if I haven't a good question? IMO, the general rules of the SEC are to strict to help any newcomer, and if the asks something wrong, he gets downvoted i guess.

Comment: That's just the risk of placing a bounty. It's like an advertisement; if that doesn't attract any attention / new customers, you lost your money. Sad but true ...

Comment: No, it isn't. Your question might be very important for you, but increased visibility for your question means *less* visibility for the other questions. That's not fair, that's why there are only a limited number of possibilities to increase your views.

Comment: "What if I haven't a good question?" - Why don't you have a good question?  That is indeed a problem.  You need to improve and clarify your question.

Comment: I did, but it seems that only homeworks for lazy students are good questions. This community is also BS.

Answer (score -1):

In relation to questions that are relevant to more than one site; It is acceptable to delete and re-ask on another community's site:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/200228

Comment: This isn't asking about questions that were off topic and should have been posted on another site.

Comment: @Servy this  is an option for questions that are on topic and could have been posted on another site...