# Migrate to another Stack Exchange site without closing

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, site-recommendation, migration, off-topic

The current process of flagging a post for migration to another Stack Exchange website is as follows:

1. Flag
2. It should be closed for another reason
3. Off-topic because
4. This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Clearly, the request to close is a prerequisite to mark the question as "belongs to another SE site". But we know that SE sites are not mutually exclusive, for example Cross Validated, Data Science, and Stack Overflow have a lot of intersections. For example, when somebody asks a question about how to implement a certain statistical algorithm, statisticians, data science professionals and computer scientists can help. So there might be cases where a question is better suited for one of these sites, while the best option would be to keep the question in the one it is originally asked in as well.

**So there might be cases where a "replicate/cross-post" would work better than "migrate", simply because the question is not off-topic, but is in the intersection of multiple SE sites, and naturally belongs to more than one.**

Wouldn't it be better if we had the following two flags:

1. Close and migrate
2. Keep open and migrate

I know people can comment on posts and recommend the user to cross-post, but wouldn't it be better to make this a formal feature of SE?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This specifically runs afoul of something that we already require - questions should not be duplicated between the sites without being specifically rewritten with that site in mind. [Cross posting is strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Additionally, while the most emphatic rule of migration is "Don't migrate crap", the most important consideration of whether you should migrate at all is whether a question is on topic where it was asked or not. If it's on topic, the question stays and **is not** migrated. There may be some exceptions made if the OP specifically requests migration but that's up to the site moderators to decide in each case.

Making it possible for users (or even only moderators) to rubber stamp identical questions on multiple sites goes against the current policies and, as such, this request should be declined.

It's important to remember that questions must be narrow enough to be answered relatively succinctly. If a question requires someone who is an expert in multiple fields to answer, it's likely to be too broad. It should be divided up into more specific questions and those questions should be asked on the sites that specialize in those topics.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Was just asking, good to know the answer, so that in case somebody has the same question in the future, they can benefit from the answer. Thanks!