# Profile: Stack Overflow profile Top Tags are not updating

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

Last week I have updated my Stack Overflow email address from EMAIL SETTINGS option. After that, I didn't get any confirmation email for my new email and from last week [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6012880/rajib-karmaker?tab=profile) top tags section are not updating.

Comment: [Cross posted at Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372052).

Comment: [Cross posting is not permitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64069#64069) (applies to meta sites as well).

Comment: should I delete this post from here?

Comment: it's updated. Thank you.