# Is copy-pasting your own answer between Stack Exchange sites appropriate?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, cross-posting

I recently [posted a question and self-answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727606/how-do-convolutional-layers-cnns-work-in-keras). Because (in my opinion), it's the best contribution I have made to the site thus far, I would like to post it on other topic-appropriate Stack Exchange sites such as [datascience.stackexchange.com](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Is this appropriate?

I understand that the fact that it's a Q&A pair can affect whether this behavior is okay. As a result I would also like to know your judgement if it was just a plain answer that would answer questions on different sites.

Comment: Are you looking to answer an existing question there or do another self-answer?

Comment: @Laurel both - the first part asks if posting the self answer is appropriate; the second part asks what if it was just a plain answer. How can I clarify this?

Comment: To the first part: No. Cross-posting the same question on two SE sites is discouraged. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is probably a soft no.

It's probably not really against the letter of the rules but kinda feels off by the spirit of it. I don't think there should be any penalty for it though.

If it was just an answer I'd suggest referring back to the SO question and tailoring the answer to the site.

It gets trickier with a QA pair on a different site but trying to adjust for the audience rather than an exact repost feels like a good idea - what's important to a developer may vary from what a data scientist may find useful, and the varying perspective might add to the utility of the 'cross posted' question and answer.