# About Codes of Conduct and the welcoming spirit of SE

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct, welcoming

As a casual user of SE I have some concerns about the CoC and the welcoming spirit of SE.

My personal experience is this: More often than not I feel unwelcome (as a novice and non-specialist) because of the kind of my questions and the way in which I ask them.

On the one side I'm told that SE is open and open-minded and aimed at giving space to holism and interdisciplinarity. But many "holistic" questions are refuted for being "too broad","too unspecific", "too unprofessional".

Especially, asking the same question at different SE sites is regularily criticizied for being "rude" or otherwise "bad" - even though it was intended to  be just "interdisciplinary". For me there seems to be no reliable CoC that allows me - or the moderators - to distinguish between good and bad ways of asking broad and interdisciplinary questions, possibly on different SE sites.

Comment: Common mistake. The CoC is **not** about good or bad questions. It's **not** meant to be a shield allowing people to post any question. It just tell the user how they should behave, and to be nice towards other people. Downvoting a question or closing it is NOT being evil/toxic/unfriendly/etc. It's just that: downvoting or closing, due to the question being not good enough or not fitting the site.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard Fully agree with that, what is strange is that all efforts to be welcoming fail to address the problem which cause so much people to make this mistake and feel unwelcome...

Comment: @Tensibai true, guess it's human nature to raise a shield when you're doing something wrong and blame others, or something else.

Answer (score 29):

The problem here isn't how "welcoming" or "open-minded" a SE site is. The problem here appears to be *your interpretation* of the scope of these sites.

If users or moderators tell you the question is too broad for the site you posted it on, it's likely that the question is not a good fit for that site. If this is something that happens to you more often, you may want to go through the site's help center again, there are instructions in there on what (not) to ask, and how (not) to ask it.

You're expected to pick the right site to ask your question on. "Blindly" throwing questions at several sites in the hopes that a question sticks and gets answered will generally result in a negative experience.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, I'll try to keep it in mind!