# Am I allowed to ask the same question in two different sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

If I ask a question in one stack site and don't get an answer, is it a good idea to ask the same question in a different stack site ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score 3):

Each site has its own strict on-topic definition. While there are some sites with overlapping definitions, this isn't all that common. It is unlikely that you can cross post a question without any changes and have it be on-topic on both sites. If you tailor it to the second site, then that's fine. Also consider making a bounty on the original question to drive more attention to it.

Comment: _It is unlikely that you can cross post a question without any changes and have it be on-topic on both sites_ - That's not even the point that should be emphasized. Even if a question _is_ perfectly on-topic at two different sites, it shouldn't be asked on both.

Comment: @n8te That's not true. If a question is on-topic and tailored appropriately to two sites then it can be asked at both. As the question you linked to above says.

Comment: OP isn't talking about tailoring to two sites. Asking the same question on two sites shouldn't be done.