# What's the policy on crossposting unnoticed posts from beta communities?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites, cross-posting, site-crossover

I have posted a question that in my opinion fits best into a beta community.

Overall, the attention was not satisfactory although I even posted a bounty and the limited response I got was positive. Despite currently being the only bountied question it has been viewed about 30 times in 10 days and about a third of the views seem to be my own. I believe the question itself should be relatively easy to answer for people familiar with the subject, hence I believe the low impact is related to the early beta stage of the community.

Is it acceptable to cross-post an unnoticed question from a beta community into a more mature related but thematically less on-point community?

For reference, the beta community under consideration is Earth Sciences; I'm considering a cross-post into Physics and the relevant question ([What is the use of HV or VH polarization in Radar?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19412/what-is-the-use-of-hv-or-vh-polarization-in-radar)) is about radar.

Edit: Generally, cross-posting is deemed unacceptable ([Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)). However, this question seems to be a special case of the above. I can see a point to be made, that cross-posting is never allowed and that the beta status is irrelevant. At the same time I can see an argument for the opposing viewpoint, since many sensible strategies proposed in the case of mature sites (i.e. rephrasing the question, editing the question....) may not be helpful if the general traffic on a beta site is so low that the answer is simply not read by anyone, hence I feel that my question is not a straight forward application of the above one.

Comment: I just want to note that the question that brought me to meta has meanwhile been answered satisfactory. Still, I believe that it might be an interesting thing in general to clarify whether cross-posting from immature sites is justified or not.

Comment: Seems to be a dup of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917.  The "beta" part doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @D.W. Imho, its not straight forward to say wether the linked post adresses the same question. In a way that is exactly what i am trying to clarify with my question. Summing up, meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917's answer, states that it is generally not acceptable to cross-post. Fair enough. My question is exactly wether this changes if one of the sites is an immature beta community. The strategies advocated in the "standard answer" (ie editing your question, rephrasing the question) seem not helpful if the general traffic on a site is so low that no one is there to read it...

Comment: The question about radar seems better asked on [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radar), physics.SE is going to get you an entirely different kind of answer (not about remote sensing, more about the physics).

Comment: If the policy was different for beta sites, it would have been indicated in that answer.  There are a *lot* of beta sites, so this is not a rare special case.  If no one is reading your question, perhaps delete it and re-post it elsewhere.  Our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers.