# Where do I go for questions involving two different Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question involving LaTeX and bookbinding. Which do I go to, or is there a Stack Exchange site specifically for questions in multiple other Stack Exchange sites?

The questions entail writing the `\title{}` on the inside of the pages in `[twoside]{scrbook}` and how to bind a book with something transparent.

Comment: Could you edit the question you're looking to ask into this question? The specifics of it might help us find the right site.

Comment: @Spevacus There you go :) why didn't I do that in the first place?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @gnat I don't think this is a duplicate as the question in question would not _equally_ fit both sites. For instance, bookbinding on LaTeX might be okay, but LaTeX on Arts and Crafts definitely won't. Voting to leave open

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask the LaTeX question on [Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) and the bookbinding one on Crafts, see [their bookbinding tag](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-binding). Make sure the actual individual questions are on-topic for each site.

The key point here is that you don't have *a* question, you have two questions, the scope of which are covered by different stacks. Generally speaking, when you have a question spanning topics as various as LaTeX editing (which is rather immaterial) and bookbinding (which is rather "physical"), you probably want to split that "one" question into several subquestions, which you each ask on the relevant sites, linking to the others if relevant.

Comment: Converting the comment into an answer as I didn't find an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Good point, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Book binding questions can be asked on Latex.SE, see these bookbinding questions:

- [can LaTeX help with book binding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284034/163358)
- [Printing a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26669/163358)

Simply add the [book-design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-design) tag. Nowadays many companies offer one-off and [small-run books as a service](https://www.google.com/search?q=one-off%20and%20small-run%20books%20as%20a%20service) which offers professional results for under $100 (single book), and additional books for a small additional cost. Binding your own on the cheap can be done with a photo album.

As [explained by Paul Dulaney](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95078/163358) on Latex.SE: "LaTeX is to a book what a set of blueprints is to a building.". Simple laminating is something that can be asked on our [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bself-publishing%5D+laminating) site. Where you ask will determine the results that one would expect, asking on Arts & Crafts or DIY would produce a different answer than one of our more professional sites devoted to the main (more complex) subject of your question.