# What other Stack Exchange sites support crossposting like Mathematics and Math Overflow?

Tags: support, cross-posting, site-crossover

[The general rule is no crossposting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069), but what other Stack Exchange sites like [Math and Math Overflow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32559) approve this after seven days?  Can we list them here?

I can't remember where, but I remember some other Meta post on some science Stack Exchange site discussing crossposting, and some users there approve.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to have arisen in the context of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244267/how-did-unless-evolve-to-mean-if-not) being shopped around various Stack Exchange sites, including [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815693/why-does-unless-mean-if-not) and [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/76583/why-does-unless-mean-if-not).

Instead of trying to find a list of venues it might be possible to post a particular question to and stay technically within their rules, I think it'd be better to carefully look at what's on-topic, both in letter and spirit, on a particular site you are considering posting to. And not to keep trying to find new angles on a question that has basically been answered.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why your Meta profile says that you've been a member for just 13 days even though you've been here far longer? (You're also the #1 ranked new user) [[Same thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers) with your account on EL&U]

Comment: @CDR my account accidentally got wiped network-wide. For Money and StackOverflow they restored my old user id, for the other network sites I set up new profiles and they've reassociated my posts with them.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 5):

Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange has a similar policy (cross-posts are allowed after 7 days); see [this answer](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/231/32711) to their FAQ. Since it mentions 'other Stack Exchange sites', it doesn't seem to be a mutual agreement.