# Should vimscript questions be on SO or on Vi and Vim?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I regularly search for and ask questions regarding the vimscript programming language. Sometimes I find the answer on [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com), and sometimes on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), but it's quite frustrating having to resort to Google instead of being able to search directly in the right Stack Exchange site. When I'm programming in most programming languages, I can just search in Stack Overflow directly, with the language tags, so that I don't get false hits on similarly named language constructs in other programming languages.

Here's an example; I asked [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29611/how-do-you-explicitly-throw-an-error/29612#29612) on Vi and Vim, where it doesn't have an answer. Then a little while later I thought of searching on Stack Overflow, where it already [has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312813/vim-showing-an-error-message-from-a-vim-script). Does it make sense that we're duplicating efforts here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about [Vim script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Vim_script) are on-topic on both [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) as well as [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com), so you can ask them on either site.

Vim script is a scripting language for a tool commonly used by programmers, and is definitely on-topic on Stack Overflow, and vim (for which vimscript is a synonym) is quite an [active tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim). Note that uses of Vim that are not programming related are off-topic as stated in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim/info), but your question certainly counts as programming.

While I'm less familiar with the Vi and Vim site, it's apparent that questions about Vim script are on-topic there as well, based on the [activity in that tag](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tags/vimscript), as well as the description in the [tag wiki](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tags/vimscript/info).

Generally, I've found search engines to be a better tool for finding the answers to my questions. The kinds of questions I'm personally interested in lead me to Stack Overflow most of the time, but every now and then I end up on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Searching on specific Stack Exchange sites separately would make it harder for me to find what I want. If you do want to search specifically across only the network, you can use the [Stack Exchange search](https://stackexchange.com/search) for that.

Your concern about duplicating effort across sites is valid. As discussed in [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) you shouldn't *knowingly* post a question on some Stack Exchange site, if the same question is already posted on another Stack Exchange site. However, if it happens accidentally, as it did in your case, it's fine. A certain amount of duplicated effort is bound to occur as the number of sites across the network expands, and the scope of individual sites change over time. You can help mitigate this to a large extent yourself, by not restricting your search to a single site to begin with.

I do like that you didn't simply link to the accepted answer on Stack Overflow, or copy the answer verbatim, but instead expanded upon it by providing a bit of code, as well as an explanation of what the code does.