# Can I copy and paste (with citation) someone else's unanswered question on a Stack Exchange site onto another site, if it's on-topic on the new site?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I found a question on CS Stack Exchange, which was asked in March. It is too old for migration. There are unanswered electronic questions on Stack Overflow as well. Specifically, I am talking about this question on **CS Stack Exchange**:
[Propagation and contamination delays with different delays for rising and falling edges](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/138232/115941). **This question has also been asked on Stack Overflow**: [Propagation and contamination delays with different delays for rising and falling edges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66855042/12311164) **A very interesting question, but no answers on either site**. There is a comment saying it should be asked on EE Stack Exchange, but the Original Poster has not asked it there. On behalf of the Original Poster, can I copy and paste their question to Electrical Engineering, with a proper citation? I am interested in this question.

Example citation:

[Mergasov](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/98323/mergasov), [Propagation and contamination delays with different delays for rising and falling edges](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/138232), copyright 2021-03-28, licensed under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), originally posted on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Any subsequent modifications are indicated in the edit history for this current post.

This happens because the scope of the site is not enforced properly on other Stack Exchange sites. See: [Do you want the electronics questions from Stack Overflow to be moved to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7362/238188)

Since we have no control over other sites, the only option is to manually copy and paste (with citation) the closed/unanswered questions which can't be migrated, if we find them useful and interesting. Is this okay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @cigien no it does not, since that question is about cross-posting, mine is about copying and pasting another user's question

Comment: "It might be too old for migration. " threshold for migration is 3 months

Comment: How does it matter if you or the OP cross-posts? The result is the same.

Comment: As per the answer on the target, cross-posting is not allowed. I don't see why there would be any difference at all if the cross-posting was done by different users, or the same one.

Comment: @cigien whether it is allowed or not depends on the individual site.

Comment: @Anon IF there are sites that allow cross-posting, then you should ask on THEIR meta sites if this also counts for unrelated users.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The question was migrated

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but even if individual sites have different rules, those rules would be the same regardless of who owns the original post, right? If you think there is some difference in that regard then please make that explicit in the question, and preferably link to the suggested duplicate target, and explain why your question is not covered there.

Comment: @cigien I mean if a site likes a question they might allow it. There is nothing to stop questions from being cross-posted, unless this is detected by the software and prevented. How would the mods from other sites be aware of cross-posting (unless they are active on other site as well)?

Comment: You said in your question that you're going to give credit to the original - won't be very difficult to notice that it is cross-posted ....

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that question has already been cross-posted. See the edit in my question.

Comment: @cigien that question has already been cross-posted. See the edit in my question.

Comment: I don't really understand why a question asking if a specific question would be welcome on a specific site would be migrated here... But the smartest move here would be to quit [your SO vs. Electronics crusade](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407443/6380541), and finally accept that people can choose where to post their questions, and that they may not always choose the site you prefer.

Comment: Hello, I'm the poster of these questions. I have no time to investigate whether they allow to copy-past the original question to other sites or migrate it, but as for me, I wouldn't mind if you do it. Please, share a link.

Comment: @tinkeringbell The question was moved because the issue is not site specific and applies to all sites. In addition, I appreciate your help in dealing with this question and user.

Comment: @Mergasov What would definitely be permitted is for you to delete the question on both [cs.se] and [so] and then post it on [electronics.se].

Comment: @Tinkeringbell yes I have accepted this. As I said "Since we have no control over other sites, the only option is to manually copy and paste (with citation) the closed/unanswered questions which can't be migrated, if we find them useful and interesting." But I did not get an answer to this question