# Ebooks or Graphic Design Stack Exchange for a question about using InDesign to create ebooks?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, cross-posting

I have a question about exporting eBooks from InDesign: [How to tell InDesign to skip color in css export for the ePub export](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/154613/how-to-tell-indesign-to-skip-color-in-css-export-for-the-epub-export)

I asked it on Graphic Design Stack Exchange. But I do not know if that was a good place for the question. Would Ebooks Stack Exchange have been a better place?

Is this a question that could belong on both sites at the same time?

Comment: As far as your second question in this question goes (which is frowned upon btw), please see the FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 4):

If either of those two sites has a tag for InDesign then I think it would be reasonable to ask your question on the one you think it might be a better fit for.

If it gets a poor reception or no interest there, then if the other has that tag too, I think you should delete your question from the first site and ask it on the second site instead.