# Closing a question as duplicate of a question on sister-site?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18252/4257) on stats.stackexchange has several duplicates on stackoverflow (see the comment for one). In truth, the content does match both sites (statistics related but also a programming how to in R).

Do I still vote to close as duplicate (can I even?), close as needs to migrate, or just leave it be (note: given the comment, probably noone will actually post an answer, so leaving the question open is just as silly).