# Can questions on different Stack Exchange sites be marked as exact duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

This question on [Health Beta](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/815/can-being-cold-or-wet-be-a-significant-influence-in-getting-the-common-cold/830?noredirect=1#comment15815_830) seems to be the same as this question on [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/88/does-being-cold-increase-your-chances-of-catching-the-common-cold). They both were well-received and have several answers. Can, and should, anything be done to link them together or mark them as a duplicate?

I personally find there is quite a bit of overlap in different sites in the Stack Exchange network and it could benefit from more clearly defined boundaries for each site.

Comment: Are you asking if cross-site duplicates are possible?  Or are you requesting the feature?

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151729/242209

Comment: What's wrong with overlap? It just means there are multiple places that can accept certain questions, probably giving subtly different answers.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Having the same questions on different websites divides the contributors' efforts. I wish the same questions posted on different Stack Exchange sites could be marked as exact duplicates.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Sometimes; when this happens, it's because [the asker was sloppy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260752/two-posts-enter-one-post-leaves-merging-identical-questions-probably-inten) and didn't bother to consider the purpose of having two sites available to ask on. I'm not sure this is common enough to be worth coding a feature for, or bad enough that the risk of close-happy voters is outweighed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I often see questions pertaining to machine learning being asked on different Stack Exchange websites by different users (unintentionally). I don't know how common this is in other fields, but I have seen happened quite a few times especially in websites with a large overlap (e.g. unix - askubuntu - superuser, or statistics - data science - stack overflow).

Comment: @JAL I already know that cross site postings are not supposed to happen so what should be done if a duplicate is found?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I never said anything's wrong with it but I thought the consensus is that it shouldn't happen. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @Celeritas: There's a fair few downvotes on the accepted answer; http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012 captures my thoughts better, and see also [Robert Cartaino's views on what to do with cross-posted dupes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713).

Comment: @NathanTuggy this is one of the reasons why I think there are too many sites that overlap, it actually makes it harder to reach people with valuable input. Also if you do want to search for a question, it would be more difficult to search each SE site than just one.

Answer (score 2):

> Can, and should, anything be done to link them together or mark them as a duplicate?

No. The same question can have different point of views from where the answers originate from (although they can be similar). This is not a bad thing. Sometimes the subjects of sites do overlap, which is hard to prevent since some fields of expertise are related to each other.

You could 'link' to the other question from an answer you have posted (where the contents itself stands on its own), or a comment on the question. This gives enough context for users visiting the site to find it.