# Allowing straightforward duplicates to be linked from main meta to specific meta

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

This question is *not* about cross duplicates among all meta sites, which is discussed here:
[What to do with cross site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/163449)

There are certain duplicates which are too straightforward to be re-answered.  Those are asked in a specific per-site meta but are already answered in main meta (i.e., here).

For example, a question asked in Hinduism Meta:
[Can we make "giving reasons" mandatory in case of up/down voting?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/492/1049)
is a straightforward duplicate of:
[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/163449)
I believe it won't serve any purpose if flagged, as moderators probably can't close it.

Isn't it worth it to be marked as duplicate?

In case of rejection of this feature, would it be good to reply with a link (to Meta) only answer or simply copy-paste from Meta (if the answer is good)?

Comment: You seem to think that people should be made aware of not only their site specific meta but also the Stack Exchange general one. We think that's not needed - that a question can be duplicate across many metas, meaning users don't have to venture outside of their site of choice.

Comment: @Oded If they can be affected by decisions taken outside their little community, then shouldn't they be made aware?

Comment: @muru - not everyone needs to know about the whole system. It is big and complex and frankly, if they want to know it isn't difficult to find out. I am talking about pushing people towards more complexity, when it isn't usually needed.

Comment: @muru, actually I have incorporated other reasons for why the closing the dupes should be allowed. Your reason is also important. Hence feel free to edit my answer, if it adds value. If someone requests some feature in specific meta and if someone supports it then it will work against the interest of the main meta, where the similar suggestion was Not supported.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that is a good idea.

Not all users are aware that they are a user of network of sites and as such should be served by only their own site meta.

In cases where a good duplicate exists on Meta Stack Exchange but not on the site-meta I often write a tailored answer where I use, attribute and link to questions and answers on MSE.

An example of such approach I have shown [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318347/578411) where I combine info from MSE with my own work while attributing to the original posts and authors.

Another example is [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311394/578411) from [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf).

Using above approach gives you the best of two worlds: You connect to existing knowledge while you can adapt the answer that is specific for the community. When the same question comes up again on the site meta you have a good, tailored and community specific canonical duplicate target.

Answer (score -1):

**The straightforward duplicates should be allowed to be closed, if it was already asked on the main meta.SE.**

There is a Nice point in @muru's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276854/allowing-straightforward-duplicates-to-be-linked-from-main-meta-to-specific-meta/276912#comment896883_276854):

> If they can be affected by decisions taken outside their little community, then shouldn't they be made aware?

Example: A user suggests something in a smaller meta. If anyone with valid reasons actually supports that feature in his/her answer. That answer is accepted &/or upvoted by others. It gives an impression of a well received feature request.
Now, it turns out that this feature is already rejected in the main meta a while back. It creates a confusion or dilemma. Hence, if the generic decisions are going to be taken in the main meta, then its posts should be linkable within the smaller meta-s.

To respond to @Oded's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276854/allowing-straightforward-duplicates-to-be-linked-from-main-meta-to-specific-meta#comment896863_276854):

> You seem to think that people should be made aware of not only their site specific meta but also the Stack Exchange general one.

Not intended for the people to be aware about main meta.SE. Just that the Q should be closed with the link to the duplicate Q in meta.SE. It just says that, the text to your answer is already present here. This is similar to putting wikipedia link in any Q&A.

> We think that's not needed - that a question can be duplicate across many metas, meaning users don't have to venture outside of their site of choice

It's not many meta-s. It's only meta of your choice and main meta.SE.
Nevertheless such ventures are happening, when a question asked by user is migrated. For example, in past my Q from SO got migrated to Programmers.SE. After that I had to open an account to be able to accept the correct answer. The closing of duplicate is easier, where the user can just simply read the post without opening an account and there is nothing to be accepted as right answer.

The other answer suggests that:

> where I combine info from MSE with my own work while attributing to the original posts and authors.

For straight forward Qs, own work is not required. e.g. the 2 Qs in the OP. Hence putting an answer, just makes link only answers.