# Should I paraphrase the cross-site duplicate when posting it as an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, site-crossover

This Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258778/what-does-l-in-lseek-of-unistd-h-mean) had an answer on Software Engineering. After reading this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/275467) here, I went ahead and posted an answer, since I feel like that question is on topic on both sites.

In this case, I wanted to paraphrase the answer a little bit, but what should I do when the cross site duplicate is exactly as I think it should be? Copy paste it and then link to the authentic answer at the last sentence? If not, then what?

Comment: I have seen that in SO already @Glorfindel, so I know what you mean, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. Giving the overlapping scopes of some of the sites in the network, there are bound to be some duplicate or near-duplicate questions, and thus answers. Paraphrasing and adjusting the answer so that it's more appropriate for the site is nice, but sometimes it's just not necessary.

According to CC BY-SA 3.0, the license applicable to all Stack Exchange content, you have to [show and hyperlink the author names](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/), but in practice that's often omitted.

It's nice if you use blockquotes (`>`) to visually indicate that it's a quoted answer instead of your own words. It could get messy with the nested quotes, but I think it'd work:

> As noted at the foot of http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/lseek.2.html:
>
> > ```
> >  A seek() function appeared in Version 2 AT&T UNIX, later renamed into
> >  lseek() for ``long seek'' due to a larger offset argument type.
> > ```

<sub>(copied from [this Software Engineering answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/244582/173647) by [mc110](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/129599/mc110))</sub>

Comment: I think doing the last part would add "complexity for the reader", and since I am crediting the authentic answer at the end, it might not be needing. What I am trying to say, is that the future reader doesn't really care about where did the answer came from. However I do, as the answerer. So, linking to the authentic one at the end of my post seems like the sweet spot for me. Otherwise, it might get too messy in general, as you say. The last part of your first paragraph was all I needed to hear, thanks (again ;) ).

Comment: If you are providing a verbatim answer from somebody else, even if attributing it to them, I would make it a community wiki post. It doesn't seem kosher to be getting votes (up or down) for an answer if the *only* thing you've done is copy and paste it from somebody else.

Comment: Well, sometimes *finding* the correct information is just as important as writing it. I'd make such a post Community Wiki if I found the answer through a comment on the question.