# Should a question be posted on the site with the most expertise or the most interest?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, cross-posting

Should we give priority to interest or expertise when choosing where to post a question?

A question may be of more interest to users on one Stack Exchange site, but the users on a different site may have more relevant expertise.
For example, the answer to a question about some medical magnetic resonance methods might be of most interest to users on [Medical Sciences SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/), but users with relevant expertise might be better found on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

I am curious about this since I asked ["What is the chance that the Sun will not rise tomorrow?"](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/53248/47727) on [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/), which turned out to be somewhat controversial with both downvotes and a supportive bounty offered by another user. I believed most of the possible answers (for the conditions I specify) require astrophysical expertise, but the motivation for the question comes from the classic statistical ["Sunrise problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem), so the answer might be more interesting to some users on [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  I didn't want to cross post, so I chose expertise.

Comment: The answer's probably not of special interest to Cross Validated users; any more than the rate of Prussian cavalrymen's dying from horse kicks is.

Comment: @Scortchi-Reinstate-Monica I only mentioned my specific Astronomy SE question since it inspired my general Meta question here about interest vs expertise when choosing a site.  I agree there is unlikely to be mass interest in my question on Cross Validated, which is why I specified that it "might be more interesting to some users". They are at least more likely to be familiar with the  "Sunrise Problem", since it is mentioned in many Statistics textbooks.

Comment: Well, it's as @BryanKrause says: the statistical interest is in the particular method illustrated by Laplace & not in the answer to your question per se. I wanted to point out that the question asked on Astronomy wouldn't fall within the scope of C.V. (Not that it wasn't well written, enlightening, or entertaining - there are a couple of papers you reference that I intend to read.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's difficult to answer this question broadly for all cases. I can make some suggestions for specific cases, though.

If you're asking about *physics of MRI* or how the machine works, that's not really an area of interest *within medicine*. Physicians, nurses, and technicians may have some general idea of the process, but it's likely to be short of what you'll read on Wikipedia. The people who, say, build and design an MRI machine are going to be *physicists* and *engineers*. I suppose for your title question this answer would be "the site with the most expertise and most interest".

If you're asking about *scan settings* on an MRI *in clinical or research practice*, though, Medical Sciences may be more appropriate, or Psych & Neuro if referencing MRI methods used to study the brain.

"What is the chance that the Sun will not rise tomorrow?" does not seem like a useful question on any SE site to me. You can see on the Wikipedia page you link that this is a bit of a cheeky thought experiment, there is no actual interest in that probability, just usefulness in that the Sun rising daily is a phenomenon familiar to all (perhaps less so residents of Edinburgh) which is therefore a useful tool to explain concepts (and possible missteps) in probability. A bounty means only that at least one person disagrees with me; I doubt I have a single opinion for which that is not the case.

However, if you're trying to understand the underlying concepts of probability surfaced by that example, it seems like that would be something relevant at Cross Validated; also possible that some approaches would fit at Philosophy.

You can always ask on Meta or Chat to gauge interest in a particular question, and please when you do ask your question, post it just one place at a time in the place that seems to fit best. It's possible that after you post you will find it actually belongs somewhere else, and that's okay, but it's best to keep just one copy of the question. Also, don't forget to search, possibly across multiple sites, for existing versions of your question.

Comment: This may be the first time I've ever heard Laplace's work described as "cheeky". I just gave my question as an example, since it inspired me to ask this general Meta question.

Comment: related: [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/997587)